# Changing gridview values on page changed

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview and for each row, I have updated a specific column's value.

However, I need to do this on pageindexchangedevent and I have wired up the code for this, but it does event does not break (I have a breakpoint)?

What is the best way to change a gridview's values when the page has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do your code on the grid view row data bound.

Comment: Hi, it was me who made this thread. That did work, but now I need to set the value of each column depending on the value on the column to the left. My code references the right column (something like row.Column[4] ) and then does a comparison (if it is greater than x make the value of the cell to the right someting else). But this does not work, I don't get different values based on the different values to the left column.